# Swift: Mutating array in struct

Tags: arrays, swift, replace, sub-array

I am trying to create a Matrix class in Swift  but I am getting an error on the `self.data[row * columns..<(row + 1) * columns] = data` line in my `setRow()` function. The error is 'Cannot assign value of type '[Double]' to type 'ArraySlice''

```swift
struct Matrix: CustomStringConvertible {
    let rows:Int
    let columns:Int
    var data:[Double]

    // Description
    public var description: String {
        var description = ""
        for r in 0..<rows {
            description += data[r * columns..<(r + 1) * columns].description + "\n"
        }
        return description
    }

    // Initialisation
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.data = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: rows * columns)
    }

    init(rows: Int, columns: Int, data:[Double]) {
        assert(data.count == (rows * columns),"Number of elements must equal rows * columns")
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.data = data
    }

    // Validity
    func validRow(row: Int) -> Bool {
        return row > 0 && row < rows
    }

    func validColumn(column: Int) -> Bool {
        return column > 0 && column < columns
    }

    func validIndex(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return validRow(row: row) && validColumn(column: column)
    }

    // Setters and getters
    func get(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double {
        assert(validIndex(row: row,column: column), "Index out of range")
        return data[(row * columns) + column]
    }

    mutating func set(row: Int, column: Int, value: Double) {
        assert(validIndex(row: row,column: column), "Index out of range")
        data[(row * columns) + column] = value
    }

    func getRow(row: Int) -> [Double] {
        assert(validRow(row: row), "Index out of range")
        return Array(data[row * columns..<(row + 1) * columns])
    }

    mutating func setRow(row: Int, data:[Double]) {
        assert(validRow(row: row), "Index out of range")
        assert(data.count == columns, "Data must be same length ans the number of columns")
        self.data[row * columns..<(row + 1) * columns] = data
    }

    // Swapping
    mutating func swapRow(row1: Int, row2: Int) {
        assert(validRow(row: row1) && validRow(row: row2), "Index out of range")
        let holder = getRow(row: row2)
        setRow(row: row2, data: getRow(row: row1))
        setRow(row: row1, data: holder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, `Array`'s ranged subscript deals with [`ArraySlice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice), not `Array`.

One solution, as [@vacawama says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102527/swift-mutating-array-in-struct#comment77177177_45102975), is to just create a slice of the entire input array. This can be done by subscripting with the array's [`indices`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2854166-indices):

```
mutating func setRow(row: Int, data newData: [Double]) {
    assert(validRow(row: row), "Index out of range")
    assert(data.count == columns, "Data must be same length ans the number of columns")
    data[row * columns ..< (row + 1) * columns] = newData[newData.indices]
}
```

Or in Swift 4, you can take advantage of [the `...` 'operator'](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b7af9bf/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift.gyb#L1135), which does the exact same thing:

```
data[row * columns ..< (row + 1) * columns] = newData[...]
```

But IMO, a better tool for the job here would be [`replaceSubrange(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2853120-replacesubrange):

```
mutating func replaceSubrange<C>(_ subrange: Range<Int>, with newElements: C) 
     where Element == C.Element, C : Collection
```

as it allows you to deal with an arbitrary `Collection` of new elements, meaning that you could also make `setRow` generic:

```
mutating func setRow<C : Collection>(row: Int, data newData: C)
    where C.Iterator.Element == Double { // <- in Swift 4, remove ".Iterator"

    assert(validRow(row: row), "Index out of range")
    assert(data.count == columns, "Data must be same length ans the number of columns")
    data.replaceSubrange(row * columns ..< (row + 1) * columns, with: newData)
}
```

Comment: Why does this work? `var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];  a[1..<3] = [6, 7]`.

Comment: @vacawama Because `ArraySlice` is `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` :) So the array literal `[6, 7]` is inferred to be an `ArraySlice<Int>`.

Comment: Very helpful, I was also wondering about why the above comment is valid, thank you.

Comment: In that case, couldn't he just do `self.data[row * columns..<(row + 1) * columns] = data[0..<data.count]`.

Comment: @vacawama Yup, he could, or even in Swift 4 `= data[...]` – but IMO `replaceSubrange` is better suited for the task, as it lets you deal with arbitrary collections of new elements. I'll also edit in your suggestion though (unless you want to post it as an answer)

Comment: Go ahead and edit it in because I never would have come up with that without this comment chain.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple. Didn't you want to set just a `Double` instead of `[Double]` in your function?

```
mutating func setRow(row: Int, data: Double) {
        assert(validRow(row: row), "Index out of range")
        assert(data.count == columns, "Data must be same length ans the number of columns")
        self.data[row * columns..<(row + 1) * columns] = data
    }
```

Comment: No, I want to set an array of values within my `self.data` array